# Cross Apply / Between Clause confilict and performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @Contract AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @STARTDATE AS DATETIME; 
DECLARE @ENDDATE AS DATETIME; 

SET @STARTDATE = '2014-07-01'; 
SET @ENDDATE = '2014-09-21'; 

WITH CTE (Cntr) 
     AS (SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ContractId) + ',' 
         FROM   contract 
         WHERE  clientid = 20739 
         FOR XML PATH('')) 
SELECT @Contract = Cntr 
FROM   CTE; 

SELECT DISTINCT so.ServiceOrderId, 
                C.ContractId, 
                so.CreateDate, 
                CP.AccountNumber    AS 'Customer #', 
                CT.ContractName, 
                CP.NAME             AS 'Customer Name', 
                bm.BucketName       AS 'BucketCode', 
                LISTOFNOTES, 
                C.ContractName      AS 'Contract', 
                PP.PartnerProfileId AS 'PartnerId', 
                PP.PartnerName      AS 'PartnerName', 
                stm.ServiceTypename 
FROM   ServiceOrder AS SO 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT T.BasCode + ',' 
                    FROM   TECHNICIANTRIPDETAIL TTD 
                           INNER JOIN TECHNICIAN T 
                                   ON TTD.TECHNICIANID = T.TECHNICIANID 
                    WHERE  TTD.SERVICEORDERID = SO.SERVICEORDERID 
                    FOR XML PATH('')) TEMP(LISTOFNOTES) 
       INNER JOIN Contract AS C 
               ON C.ContractId = so.ContractId 
       INNER JOIN ClientProfile AS CP 
               ON CP.ClientId = C.ClientId 
       INNER JOIN BucketMaster AS bm 
               ON bm.BucketId = so.Status 
       INNER JOIN Servicetypemaster AS stm 
               ON stm.servicetypeid = C.servicetypeid 
       INNER JOIN ContractType CT 
               ON CT.ContractTypeId = C.ContractTypeId 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN PartnerProfile AS PP 
                    ON PP.PartnerProfileId = CP.PartnerId 
WHERE  SO.Deleted = 'false' 
       AND so.CreateDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE 
       AND C.ContractId IN (SELECT * 
                            FROM   dbo.Split(@CONTRACT, ','))
```

I am using above query to get the data in report.

This query takes 4 to 5 minutes of execution time which is too much.

Strange thing that is happening with this query is if I will remove cross apply the query will run in 10 secs of time, if I keep cross apply and remove between condition in where then also query executes in 10 to 12 secs of time.

I want to understand why is such strange behavior and how cross apply and between is correlated.

Also, can someone help me optimizing this query with both Cross Apply and between clause in where condition?

Comment: Why are you calculating `@contract` as a comma delimited list then splitting it in the next statement?

Comment: That is just for example purpose, in SP I have @contract as parameter and I am passing ids in comma separated format from UI..

Comment: @DhavalShukla "a piece of advice" if you can reproduce this problem with less lines of code and provide some sample data and desired output, more people will be willing to take a shot, with this wall of code in your question most users wont even bother reading the question.

Comment: If I write dates directly in query instead of getting it from parameter, that too works for me.. That is the only reason why I have written whatever I have..

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on the columns specified in the JOIN and WHERE clauses in the subquery.  For starters, you might try and index on TECHNICIANTRIPDETAIL(SERVICEORDERID, TECHNICIANID).

Comment: Well, for starters, [stop splitting strings](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql). This is like eating spaghetti without utensils. Also, what is DISTINCT doing there? If this query produces duplicates, something is really wrong. Finally, once you clear up those things, take a look at the actual post-execution plan.